# Как легко и удобно получить от пользователя логи игры на Android 4.4+?

Tags: android, unity3d, разработка-игр, логирование

На Android 4.4+ нельзя читать чужие логи. Приложения вроде Logcat не работают. Как от пользователей в удобном виде для них и нас получить логи игры?

1. adb не предлагать.
2. Подключение к PC не предлагать.
3. root не предлагать.

Приветствуется какое-нибудь решение, которое легко запрограммировать. Или, если это возможно, что-нибудь стороннее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Unity создать класс:

```
public class LogsHelper {
    private static AndroidJavaObject m_Activity;
    private static AndroidJavaObject m_Logger;

    private static AndroidJavaObject GetActivity() {
        if (m_Activity == null) {
            var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
            m_Activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        }
        return m_Activity;
    }

    private static AndroidJavaObject GetLogsHelper() {
        return m_Logger ??
               (m_Logger = new AndroidJavaObject("com.test.LogsSender"));
    }

    public static void SendLogs() {
        GetLogsHelper().Call("sendLogs", GetActivity());
    }
}
```

В Java плагине класс:

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class LogsSender {

    public void sendLogs(Activity activity) {
        Log.d("unity", "sendLogs" );

        int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        try {
            String command = String.format("logcat -d -v threadtime *:*");
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String currentLine = null;

            while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (currentLine != null && currentLine.contains(String.valueOf(pid))) {
                    result.append(currentLine);
                    result.append("\n");
                }
            }

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/email");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"support@kek.com"});
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Logs");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, result.toString());

            activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail using..."));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Возможно понадобится `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />`.

В Unity вызываем `LogsHelper.SendLogs()`. После этого пользователю покажется окно с выбором почтового приложения. После выбора откроется приложение, где уже будут вбиты все поля, пользователю остаётся нажать только на кнопку "Отправить". После чего логи успешно будут отправлены вам на почту.